# Emails contains Image and going in Spam

Tags: php, email

I am creating a mail application which sends Email contains 1 Image(size-500KB). The mail is always going in spam folder and it always ask to 'Display Image Below'.
I am also inserting all the necessary Headers which is:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

How do i prevent mail going in Spam and Image should display without clicking 'Display Image Below'?
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `return-path` in your `headers`
like,

```
$headers .= "Return-Path: email@example.com\r\n";
```

Read [Spamassassian](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/AvoidingFpsForSenders)

Comment: i've tried putting "Return-Path: email@example.com\r\n" also but not solved :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a more advanced mail class like PHPMailer.